# 7zip PowerShell unzip script not unzipping to folders

Tags: powershell, unzip, 7zip

Trying to make unzipping 6k plus folders easier by running a script in PowerShell.
My problem is when I unzip one manually    it will unzip into the destination folder creating necessary folders in the unzipped files.

Now when I run the created script it will unzip all files but only create some sub folders while others are not.

I should be left with 12-13 subfolders with everything laid out within but with the script I have 4 subfolders and  a bunch of unzipped files.

Script
C:"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe x -y "path to zipped files" "-oDestination"

Any input on what I'm missing?

Comment: why is this tagged [tag:powershell] ?

Comment: I need a powershell script

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose your problem. See also: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can add zip files to a zip archive.  When you unzip the main archive it will not unzip the zip files inside the main zip.